# Add dictionary that contains an array type to a dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, dictionary

i have a problem putting a dictionary, that has a Vector2 array as it's value type into a dictionary that is a class attribute:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Vector2[]>> foo = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Vector2[]>>();  // OK
foo.Add("bar", new Dictionary<string, Vector2[]>()); // OK

fooAttribute.add("bar", new Dictionary<string, Vector2[]>()); // NOT OK
```

Declaration of the attribute is:

```
protected Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Vector2[]>> fooAttribute;
```

it works for local variables but it fails for the attribute with the following error:

> Error CS1061: Type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,UnityEngine.Vector2[]>>' does not contain a definition for`add' and no extension method `add' of type`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Assembly-CSharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Add` instead of `add`. C# is case sensitive.

Comment: ah silly mistake, thanks. i'm not used to method names with capital letters :/